# How can I serve stored data from web-sockets using Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, websocket, python-asyncio

TLDR; I am trying to run a client that fetches data from a web-sockets URI, and then use Flask to serve the fetched data from the sockets.

My intended workflow looks like: Read data from web-sockets (async) -> write data to a Python dict (continuously) -> read data from Python dict using GET requests on Flask (continuously)

The problem I am facing is that I am using a Python dictionary for storage, but when I read that dictionary from Flask, it does not show me updated values.

I have created an illustration with code to my problem

Client:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

SOME_URI = "ws://localhost:8080/foo"
connections = set()
connections.add(SOME_URI)


class Storage:
    storage = dict() # local storage dict for simplicity

    @staticmethod
    def store(data): # here I store the value
        a, b, c = data
        Storage.storage[a] = c

    @staticmethod
    def show(): # Here I just show the value to be used in the GET
        return Storage.storage


async def consumer_handler(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        async for message in websocket:
            await consumer(message)


async def consumer(message):
    line = json.loads(message)
    Storage.store(line) # adds message to dict


async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([consumer_handler(uri) for uri in connections])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

App:

```
from flask import Flask
from client import Storage

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


@app.route('/bar', methods=['GET'])
def get_instruments():
    res = Storage.show() # I expected here to see updated value for the dict as it fills up from websockets
    return res, 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Whenever I try to make a GET request to the Flask page, I get the value of an Empty dict (does not reflect the changes I add from the web socket). I was expecting to get an updated value of the dict with every GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two *separate* Python processes involved here -- one is the async script for ingesting data and the other is running flask. As these are separate processes, the `dict` updates that you're doing on the first process is not visible to the second process.

You need some form of IPC (Inter-Process Communication) mechanism here for data portability and/or persistence. One obvious and easier option to try is to use a named FIFO or a plain file. Depending on the level of complexity you want to handle for this, using Redis (or alike) is also another option.

Comment: I have started implementing this with Redis, thanks for pointing that out. What do you mean exactly by a "named FIFO", and what would be the implementation with a file or FIFO like in Python? (not really asking for code, just high-level explanation)

Comment: @Rey619 Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe for named FIFO. The implementation of a file is just the regular file we operate on via `open`. FWIW you can use `os.mkfifo` to create a named FIFO (which calls `mkfifo(3)` underneath).